# Monitoring DC high voltage circuit ADS1115

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

I have made a circuit for monitoring a boat battery like the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4lAjl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is working on a breadboard. I can trigger IO from ESP32 to open the MOSFET and read ADS1115 value with an error of 1 mV but I am not sure at all about resistor R3, R4 and R5? because I want to switch from 7.5 to 12 V DC battery. If I have made so mistakes kind to correct me.

Comment: I tried to move the text out of the inverters you added to your schematic. You don't mention the inverters in you text – what are they?

Comment: I have kick off the inverter just wanted to put a gate

Comment: a gate? what gate? **edit** ah, you mean "port" or something.

Comment: they are labelled clearly one going to digital output of the mcu the other one is going to analog input of ads1115 module

Comment: I was just confused by you using the word "gate"; that has a [some specific meanings in electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_(disambiguation)#Electronics) and doesn't mean what you intended to say here :)

Answer (score 2):

> *If I have made so mistakes kind to correct me*

You need a pull-up resistor on the p-channel MOSFET's gate so, I've rearranged your picture: -

[image]

I've changed R3's value to 10 kΩ as well. The other values look OK but, for the potential divider I'd want to use lower values given that it feeds an ADC input.

Comment: Thank you so much Andy for 12 volt 100A/h do you think that smd 2512 1 watt can make  the trick  for the potential divider like 3.3k and 1k

Comment: @KhalesNaim I don't understand what 100A/h means. If you meant 100 ampere_hours then that has no bearing on the matter. What is significant is the voltage and, the resistors. The power produced by the two resistors in series will be about 33 mW so virtually any SMD resistors will do the job.

Comment: I coming back to you for my last question is there a simple  way to protect the ads1115 circuit from over voltage and shortcircuit

Comment: Where is the over-voltage coming from and how does a short-circuit manifest itself @KhalesNaim

Comment: @KhalesNaim if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.